# meu arquivo python não está sendo escrito

Tags: python

Tenho essa parte de código:

```
with open('HTMLComposition.js', 'a', encoding="utf8") as JSIncludeFile:

    JSIncludeFile.write(Code = ("""
    //JavaFile
    DivsForComposition = """, divsForHTMLComposition, """
    for (let Div = 0 ; Div.lenght != 0 ; Div++ ){
        GetBodyTag = document.getElementById('ReportPlace')
        GetBodyTag.innerHTML += ${DivsForComposition}
        GetBodyTag.innerHTML += `<br>`
    }"""))
```

Não se prenda muito aos detalhes.
o arquivo criado não está sendo escrito. Ele simplesmente é criado limpo. Qual o erro no meu código?

Comment: Deve ser algum detalhe...

Comment: Só para ficar aqui, `lenght` está mal escrito e deve ser `length`.

Answer (score 2):

Você chama o método `write` do arquivo aberto passando argumentos estranhos.

O método `write` de objetos do tipo arquivo aceita um único argumento, sem nome, com o texto que deve ser escrito no arquivo.

Em vez disso, vocẽ, provavelmente achando que `,` concatena strings em Python, tenta fazer a chamada com 3 argumentos, o primeiro com o nome `code` (que não existe na assinatura da função - só isso já causaria uma exceção do tipo `TypeError`).  Depois vocẽ encerra a string e coloca uma vírgula, indicando um próximo argumento - e isso causa um erro de sintaxe: se o seu código estiver realmente como está no trecho que você colou, ele **nem sequer deveria ser executado**

Ah - uma segunda olhada, entendi por que não está acotnecendo um "SintaxError" - você coloca um par extra de parênteses depois de colocar `code =` na chamada ao  `.write`. O que isso faz em Python é que os elementos dentro desse par de parẽnteses se tornam uma tupla: uma sequência em que cada elemento separado por vírgula é um objeto distinto. Também não faz sentido passar tuplas para o `.write` - se não fosse o erro em passar  `code=` do nada ali, você teria um TypeError com essa tupla.

Você deve ter se confundido com o `print`: uma função que aceita um número qualquer de parâmetros posicionais, e imprime a conversão de cada um deles para string na saída padrão. Mas a `,` no print indica a separação de parâmetros, não a concatenação de strings. Strings podem ser concatenadas em Python com o operador `+` - como acontece em Javascript. Só que essa forma não é recomendada por que envolve a difitação de muitos símbolos distintos que acabam atrapalhando a escrita e  a leitura do código:  `"palavra 1 " + variavel_1 + "palavra 2"` tem que fechar uma string, concatenar outro obejto, e concatenar a continuação da string, que tem que ser aberta de novo. Em Python a partir da versão 3.6, se usam as "f-strings" - strings começadas com o prefixo `f` antes das aspas, que permitem que expressões em Python, incluindo variáveis, sejam colcoadas entre chaves (`{}`) dentro das próprias strings. O exemplo anterior ficaria sendo: `f"palavra 1 { variavel_1 } palavra 2"`. (e nesse caso, se sua string for incluir outros conjuntos de chaves, como é o seu caso, você deve usar chaves duplas, pra que elas não sejam interpretadas como uma expressão em Python);

```py
with open('HTMLComposition.js', 'a', encoding="utf8") as JSIncludeFile:

    JSIncludeFile.write(f"""
    //JavaScriptFile
    DivsForComposition = { divsForHTMLComposition }
    for (let Div = 0 ; Div.lenght != 0 ; Div++ ){
        GetBodyTag = document.getElementById('ReportPlace')
        GetBodyTag.innerHTML += ${{DivsForComposition}}
        GetBodyTag.innerHTML += `<br>`
    }""")
```

E, algumas considerações sobre o seu código que não tem diretamente a ver com o problema atual:  você está misturando Python, strings com indentação, Javascript (sendo chamado de "Java" no comentário interno, não sei por que), HTML, e um uso ruim de maiúsculas e minúsculas nos nomes de variáveis tanto em Python quanto em Javascript nesse pequeno trecho. Certamente não é  a melhor pratica para um sistema grande - se for um script pequeno, tudo bem - mas se o trecho de Javascript que você tiver que gerar for mais extenso, é melhor usar um sistema de templates, e deixar o código em Javascript, com as indicações de variáveis e trechos a serem substituídos do lado do servidor, em um arquivo separado - veja, por exemplo, [a documentação do Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/) que é um bom engine de templates para Python.